# Integrals of $L^1$-Cauchy-Sequence which converges to zero almost everywhere converges to zero

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, cauchy-sequences

Let $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, $(g_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be $L^1$-Cauchy-Sequences of step functions $X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which converge to the same limit function almost everywhere.

Define $h_n = f_n - g_n$. Then $(h_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is an $L^1$-Cauchy-Sequence which converges to zero almost everywhere (since the sum of Cauchy-Sequences itself is a Cauchy-Sequence).

The lecture notes now say

> Since $|\int_X h \,d\mu| \leq ||h||_1$ we have $\int_X h_n \,d\mu \stackrel{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$.

I don't see where this is coming from. It has to be simple, since no further steps are given. What am I missing?

In particular I don't see why the rhs of the inequality should converge to zero.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Ok, so there is a mistakes in the lecture notes. Thank you.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Those aren't Cauchy sequences in $L^1$, with that condition the assertion holds. user7802048, what facts are known about $L^1$? Since $(f_n)$ and $(g_n)$ converge (in the $L^1$-norm) to the same $L^1$-function, it is clear that $\lVert f_n - g_n\rVert_1 \to 0$. But it may not be known that $L^1$-Cauchy sequences converge, then there's a bit more to do.

Comment: @DanielFischer lol whoops I completely missed that somehow despite reading the prompt at least five times. Thanks for catching that

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you. I think there was a mistake in the lecture notes. It should read "**If** ... then we have ..." not "**Since** ...". The proof of the first inequality is given later in the lecture notes.